# Use sed with regex to extract parts of a line in csh

Tags: sed

I have following line:

> **s**1.**p**: SomeTextWithSpaces: **ABC** = xxxxxx, SomeTextWithSpaces2 = yyy, SomeTextWithSpaces3 = zzzz

The bold text and these characters (,.:= ) constant.
I need to use `sed` on this line to print the following:

> s1.p: xxxxxx

Comment: And what have you tried? Please edit your question to show the attempt you thought should have worked, but didn't including the failed output of the above sample data. Good luck.

Comment: When you tried something like: `echo "s1.p: SomeTextWithSpaces: ABC = xxxxxx, SomeTextWithSpaces2 = yyy, SomeTextWithSpaces3 = zzzz" | sed --silent --expression="help"`, with the error: `sed: -e expression #1, char 2: extra characters after command`,   then you might need to use the [edit] option that SO has implmented to make questions better.

Comment: Using awk, you can do: `echo "s1.p: SomeTextWithSpaces: ABC = xxxxxx, SomeTextWithSpaces2 = yyy, SomeTextWithSpaces3 = zzzz" | awk -F "," '{ print $1 }' | awk -F "[:=]" 'BEGIN{ OFS=":"} { print $1,$4 }'`   (but unfortunately you **need** a solution using `sed`.

Answer (score 0):

You could use something like this:

```bash
sed -E 's/(s[0-9]+\.p:).*\sABC\s*=\s*(\w+),.*/\1 \2/g'
```

Here `(s[0-9]+\.p:).*\sABC\s*=\s*(\w+).*` matches your input line, and replaces it with capturing of group number 1 and 2, separated by space.

*CAUTION*: if you input string contains two blocks like `ABC = something, ABC = something_entirely_else` - second value will be used.

Here I assumed:

- You are using GNU `sed`. If not the case replace `\s` with `[[:space:]]`, `\w` with `[[:alnum:]_]`.
- `s1.p` can contain any positive number of digits. If only single digit acceptable, replace `(s[0-9]+\.p:)` with `(s[0-9]\.p:)`.
- your `xxxxxx` contains only word symbols. If not the case: you could replace `(\w+)` with `[^,]+`.

Comment: I figured it'd be something like that in a PCRE. In a BRE or ERE to "to match everything till the next comma" would be `[^,]*,` (assuming you're matching on a character, not a multi-char string).